# Proper typescript type aliasing

Tags: typescript

I want to apply proper alias type in typescript.

[Example]

```
type O = {
    a?: "aa",
    b?: "bb",
    c?: "cc"
}
type Str = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
type ReturnOfFoo = 'aa' | 'bb' | 'cc';

const o: O = {};

const foo = (str: Str): ReturnOfFoo => {
    if(str === 'a') return 'aa';
    if(str === 'b') return 'bb';
    return 'cc';
}

const createRandomStr = (): Str => ['a', 'b', 'c'][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)] as Str;

const key: Str = createRandomStr();
const value: ReturnOfFoo = foo(key);

o[key] = value // o[key] error occured!
```

So, I did use "If statement" below.

```
if(key === 'a') {
  o[key] = value as 'aa';
}

if(key === 'b') {
  o[key] = value as 'bb';
}

if(key === 'c') {
  o[key] = value as 'cc';
}
```

But, it is not cool.

I did write more code for type.

Is there a better way?

I can use "any" type, but that's also not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** Sorry for the misunderstanding at first glance.

Adding a cast to the last line will resolve your issue :

```
(o[key] as ReturnOfFoo) = value
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=32&pln=22&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8lC8UDeBYAUFTUCGB+AXFAETbZEA06WUARgcTTRVVgMb1GutHoC+6oSFADKwAE4IoAawggA9gDNYAbnQDw0AEoRgAVzEA7GAoBicuZIDkpS1AA+US41sPLXS6rTpWcgwGdgKDlCOEQkXk9vXwCoBXNJAAoAsUJRMQBKQm09Q2MzC3gAPmQWTABLBSTxBHhEa0t0qDEdfQNHG09qCqqJWrqaBqaWw0dnTqxmnLa3Vg8+NTQff0DWZuxgCE1sAwATOQBbNMTMkWqiqABtevJRyxu3SwBdC4BZdYALADoFABtzMQSb2AXzE2z2+wSjQAVFAAMzpR44PynMSRRbRQIyECpM5QVYQdabMEHNKQzxLGIAN2wP10ECywyMpniiDicgSWPSngScguWMR2GR2VaeXMjUQ1NpEHQQA)

Comment: The OP is trying to assign `value` to `o[key]` without lots of branching. Nothing in your link does that, and if I add it, it's an error: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8lC8UDeBYAUFTUCGB+AXFAETbZEA06WUARgcTTRVVgMb1GutHoC+6oSFADKwAE4IoAawggA9gDNYAbnQDw0AEoRgAVzEA7GAoBicuZIDkpS1AA+US41sPLXS6rTpWcgwGdgKDlCOEQkXk9vXwCoBXNJAAoAsUJRMQBKQm09Q2MzC3gAPmQWTABLBSTxBHhEa0t0qDEdfQNHG09qCqqJWrqaBqaWw0dnTqxmnLa3Vg8+NTQff0DWZuxgCE1sAwATOQBbNMTMkWqiqABtevJRyxu3SwBdC4BZdYALADoFABtzMQSb2AXzE2z2+wSjQAVFAAMzpR44PynMSRRbRQIyECpM5QVYQdabMEHNKQzxLGIAN2wP10ECywyMpniiDicgSWPSnjkFyxiMQ1NpEHQQA